# How I can change all symlink to the new path

Tags: scripting, symlink

Please, I want to change the symlink to the new path
My symlink's in this form

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 s01 s01 56 Mar 22 13:17 zmjppcxlpq2m.png -> /home/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/zmjppcxlpq2m
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 s01 s01 56 Mar 23 17:03 znviy3civtq3.jpg -> /home/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/znviy3civtq3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 s01 s01 56 Mar 24 20:07 zoi46hh4pu32.jpg -> /home/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/zoi46hh4pu32
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 s01 s01 56 Mar 23 18:22 zqt0h1gy9e4c.png -> /home/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/zqt0h1gy9e4c
```

I transferred all files to a new portion from `/home` to `/home2`

So I want to change all symlinks to the new path. Ex:  Old:

```
zmjppcxlpq2m.png -> /home/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/zmjppcxlpq2m
```

I want to have

```
zmjppcxlpq2m.png -> /home2/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/zmjppcxlpq2m
```

for all files. what can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the target of a soft link without deleting the old one by forcing `ln` to do so.

```
ln -f -s /new/location/to/link newlink
```

Eg:

```
ln -f -s /home2/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/zmjppcxlpq2m zmjppcxlpq2m.png
```

or you can do an atomic replacement with mv:

```
ln -s /home2/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/zmjppcxlpq2m new_zmjppcxlpq2m.png
mv new_zmjppcxlpq2m.png zmjppcxlpq2m.png
```

To change all links in some directory, try with something similar to:

```
find /dir/with/symlinks/ -lname "/home/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/*" \
    -exec  sh -c 'ln -sf `echo $(readlink $0) | sed s/home/home2/` $0' {} \;
```

be careful backup all symlinks before execute any command

Comment: I did not understand,My Links in front of you, What i do, I can not set the commands

Comment: also I did not understand, Why you not use my link's In your explanation, old symlink and new symlink, Even I understand that I change, old
**/home/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/zmjppcxlpq2m**  new **/home2/s01/public_html/cgi-bin/uploads/00029/zmjppcxlpq2m**

Comment: **Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees, we have succeeded**

Thank you very much